# How to remove Discovery from Disqus

Tags: disqus

I have installed Disqus on my site and can not get the Discovery section to disappear under the comment box.  I have followed all the documentation I have found online, but nothing will make it disappear.

Here's a screenshot on my site:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9940352/public_images/disqus.jpg

Has anyone figured out a way to hide this?

Comment: Looks like now you want to go to https://disqus.com/admin/settings/ads/ to disable ads.

Comment: If you want to disable Disqus ads, this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131980/how-do-i-disable-or-hide-the-unwanted-disqus-ads-on-my-website/49132069#49132069

Answer (score 6):

This was recently moved to separate it from the "Ads" settings.

It's in the Disqus admin settings under the "General" tab and it's a checkbox that says "Show links to discussions taking place on your site in the Discovery box."

Note that you must be logged in with the primary owner account of the site to change it, which is why you might not see it.

Comment: I tried this box, but it did not remove the links. Has this changed since you posted here? Do you have to upgrade to a paid account or something to remove this now?

Answer (score 0):

For disabling ads of **"Sponsored"** tabs in **Disqus** section
I have created a plugin for solving disqus ads problem maybe this plugin help you:

```
https://github.com/Muneebkh2/ads-disabler-disqus
```

If you have any other query let me know ?
Thanks.

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference. How is this plugin used? Please show how it answers the Question.

Comment: Also, if the linked content is yours, please disclose that affilication so you don't inadvently violate the guideline for [self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Example: "that I wrote", "that is mine" is enough for disclosure.