# How do I disable or hide the unwanted Disqus ads on my website?

Tags: javascript, comments, ads, disqus

> Imagine that one day, suddenly, random ads started appearing on your website...

[Recently Disqus started forcing unwanted ads inside of the Disqus comments](https://wptavern.com/disqus-hits-sites-with-unwanted-advertising-plans-to-charge-large-publishers-a-monthly-fee-to-remove-ads), displaying those nasty ads on your website(s) without your knowing. It seems that they only target the sites with "big enough" daily traffic or use some other arbitrary criteria, so the ads do not appear on all the websites, but only on relatively busy ones.

This way Disqus "forces" you to upgrade to the paid subscription plan - for the paid users these ads become optional (i.e. you can disable them in your Disqus admin panel).

What to do if you don't want to pay? How to disable these ads?
Is there an easy, quick-fix solution for this?

At least until we have the time to switch to another commenting system.

Comment: doubt there is any way. they're just being sneaky about it which in this case is bad because it's losing customers

Comment: If you like the product then pay for the service or change to another service and voice your opinion so the company knows why their free customers are leaving.

Comment: Fair enough, but this came as a changed policy and they did not even notify the respective webadmins before doing so. Hence, a temporarily solution for performing the transition would also be fair.

Comment: I understand your complaint and I'm not saying you are wrong for feeling that way and it would have been nice to be notified about the change. However this is most likely a response to paying for staff and server resources for non-paying users. It may not be the best option but I feel it's fairly standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of moment of writing, it seems that popular AdBlock browser extensions successfully block the ads. However, not all of your website visitors use adblock.

Here is a quick jQuery-based solution to hide the ads:

```
(function($){
    setInterval(() => {
        $.each($('iframe'), (arr,x) => {
            let src = $(x).attr('src');
            if (src && src.match(/(ads-iframe)|(disqusads)/gi)) {
                $(x).remove();
            }
        });
    }, 300);
})(jQuery);
```

Just insert it on your website after jQuery loads, on every page where the Disqus comments appear. The code checks periodically if there are Disqus ads present on your website and removes their container whatsover. You know, just in case if they'll try to re-appear.

Comment: This will be a cat and mouse game. Create this function to take in parameters in case they change the id/name of their ads.

Comment: @Eric Gopak not working in 2021

Answer (score 12):

You can hide the ads iframes with CSS (note that what @DanielGale said is correct - this will be a cat and mouse game, your CSS selector will have to adapt):

```
iframe[src*="ads-iframe"] { display: none; }
```

Comment: best answer, simple and mega effective. Thanks for sharing this tip Dean

Comment: This is no longer working as of Dec 2021

Answer (score 6):

I was able to remove adds with this simple CSS entry:

```
div#disqus_thread iframe[sandbox] {
        max-height: 0px !important;
}
```

This works because the ads are served in an iframe with a 'sandbox' attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Disqus has changed over time, since this question was asked. Now in 2021 Disqus uses `iframes` with indistinguishable class names and ids. I have found that when it displays ads it displays a **minimum of 3** iframes, with the 2nd iframe being the comment section itself, the first iframe and iframes after the 2nd are ads. Also Disqus developers are clever, and on the **initial load Disqus only loads 1 iframe**, being the comment section itself, and after a small **delay** ~0.5-1s it loads the ads. So you **can't remove them with plain CSS** anymore, because your CSS will usually load before the Disqus ads load, so we have to write a function with a delay, that waits for the ads to load. Then remove.

Here is my code sample in JQuery, that works for me on different sites:

```
const disqus = jQuery('#disqus_thread');

disqus.ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (disqus.children().length >= 3) {
      const comments = disqus.find('iframe:nth-child(2)').detach();
      disqus.empty().append(comments);
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```

I'm searching for the `disqus_thread` id. Then the function waits for 2s. Usually 1.5s is the longest time it takes for Disqus ads to load. So 2s is a safe spot for waiting ads to load. Then I check for how many children elements does the disqus div has. If it is fewer than 3, it means that Disqus didn't load ads, so we don't have to remove any elements. But if 3 or more children is present, we save the 2nd child which is the comment section, then remove every elements inside the disqus div, and reappend the comment section.

This is not the ideal solution. But it has worked for me so far in multiple websites.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** *Dec 2021*

As of 2021, many of the previous solutions don't work. Here's a simple solution I came up with:

The Disqus ad section comes with an `iframe` tag which has an attribute `sandbox`. So you just need to set the display of any `iframe` element to `none` that has `sandbox` defined.

```
iframe[sandbox]:not([sandbox=""]) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

*Caution:* Be careful if you have any other `iframe` tags defined in your website which has the `sandbox` attribute. This might remove all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can install this plugin for WordPress site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-disqus-ads/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in vanilla javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let disqus = document.getElementById('disqus_thread');

    let remove_ads = setInterval(() => {
        let iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

        for (var iframe in iframes) {
            if (typeof iframes[iframe].src === 'undefined') {
                continue;
            }

            if (iframes[iframe].src.match(/(ads-iframe)|(disqusads)/gi)) {
                iframes[iframe].style.display = 'none';
                disqus.style.width = '100%';
            }
        }
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function () {
        clearInterval(remove_ads);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending about 40 minutes and trying different method I came to solution with the following jquery code snipet. As we know disqus have ad section above and below the comment and all of these are in iframe with id starts like "dsq-app1320" (with only 4 digit variation) so the code snippet is

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $("iframe[id^='dsq-app']").each(function (i, el) {
        if(i===0 || i===2) {
            el.remove();
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems good. But does this code work when Disqus is loaded using lazy load?

Comment: @RamakrishnaS I have know idea about that, actually I'm a backend engineer and I was really annoyed with the disqus ads in both upper and lower section of my post's comment. I was looking for solution and posted it here after I got the result. :D

Answer (score 0):

For **disabling** ads of **"Sponsored"** tabs in **Disqus** section

your **problem** will solved by this **plugin**:

```
https://github.com/Muneebkh2/ads-disabler-disqus
```

> If you have any other query let me know ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to`<head>`tag,has worked in practice.

```
<style>iframe:not([src]){display: none;}</style>
```